# rails- display image in another app's directory in my view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image, file

I have a few rails apps set up- one is for admin and the other for signup.

The admin app has a folder for photos "adminapp/u_photos/photo_browse/photos"

On the signup side I have a public form that dispays the contents of that directory via ruby's 'find' gem and a controller action that finds them.

When a user on the signup form clicks "browse images," a modal pops up and allows them to search through the images, returning all files that match (list of files).

How would I display a thumnbnail of the image next to the file name?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer while searching:

[Rails 3, displaying jpg images from the local file system above RAILS_ROOT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11959203/rails-3-displaying-jpg-images-from-the-local-file-system-above-rails-root)

This worked perfectly, and described what I needed, which was was displaying multiple images on one page.