# Where did my filename extension go in the parameter list

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I am following this answer while trying to figure out how to display images located in my app directory [Rails 3, displaying jpg images from the local file system above RAILS_ROOT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11959203/rails-3-displaying-jpg-images-from-the-local-file-system-above-rails-root)

I've created a controller as shown there, added the `match` line to routes.rb, and in a test webpage I want to load up an image called `test.jpg` using the code

```
<img src="/serve_image/test.jpg" />
```

But I get an error saying the file `<...>/public/images/test` was not found.
Then I went and renamed my image so that the `.jpg` was gone, and then the script found my image and loaded it up as wanted.

Any ideas where the extension went? I am not sure how to debug this issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, Rails doesn't match dots in a dynamic segment. So for this route:

```
match '/serve_image/:filename' => 'images#serve'
```

`:filename` will only match up to the first dot it finds. So `/serve_image/test.jpg` will match `test` as the filename and will think you're expecting a JPG as a response. What you need to do is tell the router that you want to include the dot in the filename, something like this:

```
match '/serve_image/:filename' => 'images#serve', :constraints => {:filename => /[^\/]+/}
```

That will match anything except a forward slash, giving you your complete filename in `params[:filename]`

See [the Rails Routing guide section on Dynamic Segments](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#dynamic-segments) for more info.