# ruby on rails how to render multiple non public images

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image, private, get-request

I am developing a rails 4 image sharing app like fb and I want to protect user images

so I uploaded the images to private folder and able to to display images with send_file

but it is displaying one image and also it querying the database multiple times

is there an efficient way to display multiple private images in rails 4

I have read this [Rails 3, displaying jpg images from the local file system above RAILS_ROOT](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11959203/3949952)

it was a great solution but
it is generating multiple get requests, how to do it in a single get request or any other faster way

Thanks in advance

Comment: How are you storing your images? I mean, are you using something like Paperclip?

Comment: yes, I am using paperclip and storing under the rails.root/images