# rails 5 carrierwave no route matches for image

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, image, carrierwave, ruby-on-rails-5

I need some help. I am using rails 5 and carrierwave to upload images. the issue I am having is the images are saved but will not display, I get a no route matches GET.....  I am storing the images in a uploads folder at Rails.root since I do not want them saved in the public dir.

image_uploader.rb

```
  def store_dir
   "uploads/#{model.user_id}/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
  end
```

carrier_wave.rb

```
require 'carrierwave/orm/activerecord'
require 'carrierwave'
CarrierWave.configure do |config|
 config.root = Rails.root
end
```

This is the error that I am getting in the logs:

```
Started GET "/uploads/2/uitem/image/26/A_penrose-small.jpg" for ::1 at 2016-10-29 16:06:27 +0200

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/uploads/2/uitem/image/26/A_penrose-small.jpg"):
```

Any Help would be greatly appreciated, I have been searching all over and cannot find a solution. 
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason the image isn't being found is the web server's root is the Rails app's public directory, so it is looking for the image under "public/uploads/2/..."

Since the web server can't find the file it is passing the request to the Rails stack, and there is no route defined that matches, so it throws an error.

If you change your image upload root to be the public directory it should work as you expect.

### UPDATE

If you don't want to put the images under the public directory you can create a route and controller action to serve the images. You can use the send_file method in the controller action. Take a look at this question:

[Rails 3, displaying jpg images from the local file system above RAILS_ROOT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11959203/rails-3-displaying-jpg-images-from-the-local-file-system-above-rails-root)

---

Comment: Yes, that does work but I do not want to save the images in the public dir

Comment: Thank you for the update, that link helped a lot and no everything is working.