# CarrierWave Rails 5 cant access image

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, carrierwave, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm using carrierwave to upload and show images and everything was working fine. No idea what I've changed, or if I even changed anything, but now I get

```
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "public/uploads/event/avatar/4/party-6.jpg"):
```

I have the same problem as this guy [rails 5 carrierwave no route matches for image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40319938/rails-5-carrierwave-no-route-matches-for-image), but I can't get it fixed.

This is how I access the image

```
    <img class="img-responsive" src="<%=@event.avatar.url%>" alt="">
```

The image gets stored in that folder, I can view it, but for some reason the browser cant access it

```
def store_dir
    "public/uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
  end
```

I've tried to play around with the `store_dir`, but I can't seem to get it to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please add this to environment (development.rb) file

In rails 4.x it was

```
config.serve_static_assets = true
```

and in rails 5.x it will be

```
config.public_file_server.enabled
```

and restart rails server.

check [this](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#rails-general-configuration) for more information

Comment: Thank you. That solved it. Did they come up with this in the past week? I'm 100% sure that it was working without it before.

Comment: No, from starting it was like this only.

Comment: Strange. Like I said, I had no errors and the images were displaying. Anyway it's working now, thank you.

Comment: You welcome.. Maybe it will be a problem with restarting the server. Many time i forgot to restart server

Comment: Do you have any idea on how to solve the same problem on heroku?